# How to create dynamic measures depending on date with dynamic names based on years?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

At the moment I create a measure `marketprice` for different years as the following:

```
marketprice 2021 = CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANKVALUE(table[column1],
                    SUMMARIZE(FILTER(table, table[year] = 2021), table[column1])))

marketprice 2022 = CALCUALTE(........)
marketprice 2023 = CALCUALTE(........)
marketprice 2024 = CALCUALTE(........)
```

But this is not dynamic because next year (2023) I only need the market prices from the years 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025 (in DAX syntax: `YEAR(TODAY())-1`, `YEAR(TODAY())`, `YEAR(TODAY())+1`, `YEAR(TODAY())+2`). I don't want to change every year the measure names and year-input in the measure calculation.

I hope this is possible.

Comment: hi, the logic is not clear. What do you want to see as a result - a matrix with prices for all years or something else? How are you going to manage your visual? You gain nothig from Calculate function - you do not filtering anything in the Calculate function.

Comment: I need this four measures in a dynamic way for card visuals. So, my calculation here already gives me a result for each market price per year. But I just want the name of the measure dynamic and the year inside the calculation (next year not 2021, but 2022). The main question is not about the inside of ``CALCULATE()``, it's about creating measures in power BI, which have dynamic names depending on years.

Comment: I the name itself is not possible to change. You can use a SWITCH() function inside of a selective measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant create dynamic name of measure instead you could try this with dynamic calculation:-

```
marketprice_previous_year =
CALCULATE (
    LASTNONBLANKVALUE (
        table[column1],
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER ( table, table[year] = YEAR ( TODAY () ) - 1 ),
            table[column1]
        )
    )
)


marketprice_current_year =
CALCULATE (
    LASTNONBLANKVALUE (
        table[column1],
        SUMMARIZE ( FILTER ( table, table[year] = YEAR ( TODAY () ) ), table[column1] )
    )
)

marketprice_next_year =
CALCULATE (
    LASTNONBLANKVALUE (
        table[column1],
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER ( table, table[year] = YEAR ( TODAY () ) + 1 ),
            table[column1]
        )
    )
)

marketprice_next_to_next_year =
CALCULATE (
    LASTNONBLANKVALUE (
        table[column1],
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER ( table, table[year] = YEAR ( TODAY () ) + 2 ),
            table[column1]
        )
    )
)
```